# Creating a Tab shape with CSS or SVG

Tags: html, css, svg, css-shapes

Does anyone have an idea how to make this tab like shape :

[image]

Comment: You could use either a combination of shapes via `pseudo elements`, or draw this shape at illustration and extract it as an `svg path` or add this shape as an image and `clip` the missing part

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is an alternate approach using CSS3 transforms for achieving the required shape. Like the SVG answer, this method can also be used when the background (behind the shape) is not a solid color.

The snippet has two samples and

- One uses `transform: skew(45deg)` and `overflow: hidden` on the parent to hide the skewed area on the left side.
- Other uses a `rotateX` transform with a bit of `perspective` to produce the skewed/angled side. The `transform-origin` setting means that only one side is angled.

```css
div.a {
  position: relative;
  height: 70px;
  width: 250px;
  margin-top: 20px;
  padding: 24px 4px 0px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
div.a:before {
  position: absolute;
  content: '';
  top: 20px;
  left: 0px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  background: #c94935;
  z-index: -1;
}
div.a:after {
  position: absolute;
  content: '';
  top: 0px;
  left: -20px;
  width: 60%;
  -webkit-transform: skew(45deg);
  -moz-transform: skew(45deg);
  transform: skew(45deg);
  height: 20px;
  background: #c94935;
  z-index: -1;
}
div.b {
  position: relative;
  height: 50px;
  width: 250px;
  padding: 4px 4px 0px;
  margin-top: 40px;
  background: #c94935;
}
div.b:before {
  position: absolute;
  content: '';
  top: -20px;
  left: 0px;
  width: 50%;
  height: 20px;
  -webkit-transform-origin: left top;
  -moz-transform-origin: left top;
  transform-origin: left top;
  -webkit-transform: perspective(10px) rotateX(5deg);
  -moz-transform: perspective(10px) rotateX(5deg);
  transform: perspective(10px) rotateX(5deg);
  background: #c94935;
}
body {
  background: url(http://lorempixel.com/500/500);
}
```

```html
<div class="a">
  Lorem Ipsum Dolor Sit Amet...
</div>
<div class="b">
  Lorem Ipsum Dolor Sit Amet...
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Take a single `<div>`, and apply:

```css
div {
    background:red;
    width:500px;
    height:150px;
    position:relative;
}
div:after {
    content:'';
    position:absolute;
    background:white;
    border:40px solid;
    border-bottom:0;
    border-color:white white red red;
    top:0;
    right:0;
    width:30%;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```css
div {
    background:brown;
    width:500px;
    height:100px;
    position:relative;
}
div:after {
    content:'';
    position:absolute;
    background:white;
    border:40px solid;
    border-bottom:0;
    border-color:white white brown brown;
    top:0;
    right:0;
    width:30%;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is figure:

Setting the border of an after element so that it cancels out the top part of the shape :)

```css
.box {
  position: relative;
  background-color: tomato;
  width: 300px;
  height: 200px;
}
.box:before {
  content:"";
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  width: 100px;
  border-bottom: 15px solid transparent;
  border-left: 15px solid transparent;
  border-top: 15px solid white;
}
.box span {
  
}
```

```html
<figure class="box"><br><span>Here you get a nice folder like figure :D</span></figure>
```

Answer (score 1):

The CSS solutions create the tab shape by placing a white shape on top of the brown.  If you have something behind the shape, that might not be desirable.

Here is an SVG reproduction of your image.

```html
<svg width="396" height="120" viewBox="0 0 396 120">
  <path d="M 0,33 H 198 L 228,63 H 396 V 120 H 0 Z" fill="#c94935"/>
</svg>
```