# CSS Container Wrap shaped Polygons

Tags: css, polygon, css-shapes

How can I build the white/green Container (shaped Polygons) with CSS / CSS3 ?

[image]

Comment: You are better off doing these with SVG than CSS. While it can be achieved with CSS (ways like mentioned in jbutler483's answer), your shape is actually pretty complex in the sense that it has a lot of weird angles.

Comment: You could also have a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30441122/shape-with-a-slanted-side-responsive), [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29917180/creating-a-tab-shape-with-css-or-svg/29922567#29922567), [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5293736/css3-transform-skew?) and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19147241/skewed-borders-on-a-div) for some ideas on how to approach.

Comment: nice, Thanks for the Examples!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could use a basic `SVG` path

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/XbaKLp

```
<svg width="300px" height="100px" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
    <path d="M5 5 L170 3 L295 15 L280 95 L130 80 L110 95 L20 85" stroke="transparent" fill="#8eab32"></path>
</svg>
```

- `Mx y` represents the first coordinates;
- `Lx y` represents a straight line from previous coordinates to `(x, y)`.

(you can find further information about `path` on [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Tutorial/Paths))

---

Result

[image]

Then you may add text or markup inside the SVG using the `<foreignObject>...</foreignObject>` element, e.g. suppose we need to insert a link

```
<svg width="300px" height="100px" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
    <path d="..."></path>

    <foreignObject width="100%" height="100%">
       <a href="#">noch 356 tage</a>    
    </foreignObject>
</svg>
```

along with some basic CSS

```
svg {
  line-height: 100px;
  text-align: center;
}

svg a {
  color: #fff;
  font: 36px "Indie Flower";
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

the final result is http://codepen.io/anon/pen/QbMEeW

---

[image]

and you can even apply some `CSS` transformation to the `SVG` element itself, e.g.

```
svg {
  transform: scale(.6) rotateZ(-2deg);
}
```

so it can look as in your example.

Comment: This is a much better answer :)

Comment: jear nice! SVG is the best ?
Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

You could use a clip path for this: (although I have to admit, browser support isn't incredible):

```css
body {
  height: 100%;
  background: #222;
}
div {
  height: 100px;
  width: 200px;
  line-height: 100px;
  text-align: center;
  background: rgb(180, 255, 50);
  -webkit-clip-path: polygon(0 5%, 60% 0, 100% 20%, 98% 100%, 50% 85%, 40% 100%, 5% 90%);
}
```

```html
<div>This is clipped</div>
```

**further reading:**

- [clip path on css-tricks](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/c/clip/)
- [canIuse](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-clip-path) to see browser support

---

## SVG Approach

you could also create such a shape using SVG:

```css
html,
body {
  background: gray;
}
```

```html
<svg version="1.0" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="400px" height="200px" viewBox="0 0 100 100">
  <g fill="green" stroke="black">
    <path d="M 0 5, 60 0, 100 20, 98 100, 50 85, 40 100, 5 90z" />
  </g>
</svg>
```

**disclaimer**

Please note I am still learning SVG myself, so it may require some tweaking of values.

Comment: Thanks for the fast answer! I use the SVG´s :)

Comment: @SebastianSchmal: For this implementation, I would believe SVG would be a better option