# CSS3: Make a border is not a straight line (like picture below)

Tags: css, border

I'm a css newbie
I want to create a border as the image below, how I can do that.
Thanks so much.

[image]

Comment: Possibly related to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29917180/creating-a-tab-shape-with-css-or-svg/29922567#29922567

Comment: @Wasiq Muhammad image link in content

Comment: Having brought your image into your question, you would benefit from trimming the image to make the border you're referring to clear. Also, please add enough ("[mcve]") code for us to reproduce the problem.

Comment: @DavidThomas thank you so much!